# Getting parameter value from Javascript dynamic script

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have this piece of JS code:

```
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.id = 'LeadiDscript_campaign';
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = (document.location.protocol + '//d1tprjo2w7krrh.cloudfront.net/campaign/aa545531-face-feed-cafe-4c5e1302580a.js');
    var LeadiDscript = document.getElementById('LeadiDscript');
    LeadiDscript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, LeadiDscript);
});
```

It returns parameters that I can only access/view from Firebug.  The parameter name is 's'.  How can I access that parameter so that I can view it and display it as an HTML element?

Comment: its a script element, you can't "display" it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a variable from a private scope within the global scope you'll need to bind it to the global scope or a child of it.

```
(function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        window.s = s;
        ...
});
```

Then later, somewhere in your code, in a completely different scope, you can access it using either `window.s` or just `s` if there are no local variables of that name.